# Play a local sphere video by Aframe

Tags: video, aframe, webvr

Im trying to play a sphere video store locally in my laptop with Aframe platform. 
First, i used this video: https://ucarecdn.com/bcece0a8-86ce-460e-856b-40dac4875f15/ it worked, but when i downloaded this video and changed the links to local link: http://localhost/webvr/testvr.mp4/, it didnt work.
My browser is Chrome version 56.
This is the html code I'm experimenting with

```
<head>
  <title>My A-Frame Scene</title>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-video-     controls/master/dist/aframe-video-controls.min.js"></script>
</head>

 <body>
   <a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <video id="video_1" crossorigin           src="http://localhost/webvr/testvr.mp4/"></video>
  </a-assets>

  <a-camera position="0 0 5">
      <a-cursor id="cursor" color="yellow"></a-cursor>
  </a-camera>

  <a-videosphere src="#video_1" rotation="0 180 0"></a-videosphere>

  <a-entity video-controls="src:#video_1"></a-entity>

</a-scene>
```

Comment: try removing that extra "/" at the end of your video `src`.

Also, try going to the url "http://localhost/webvr/testvr.mp4" and make sure you can access it.

Comment: I can access my video through local host usually and I  removed "/", but its still not working and. Do you have any solutions else?

Comment: just try the same in firefox. I am getting my video played in firefox but not in chrome

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
src="/webvr/testvr.mp4"
```

Your video is stored locally so you don't need the localhost part.

Comment: i tried  it before but its not working, i donnt know why, plz help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had to run a local server on my laptop instead of opening the folder directly in my browser when I was developing with A-frame. In the event you use Linux and have python 3 installed, that would be:
1. In a terminal, navigate to the folder where your index.html and the video etc are in.
2. Then run the start the server by running the command:
 python3 -m http.server

I'm not sure where I read that this was the case, perhaps only for linux computers, when webdeveloping locally. But perhaps using a server somewhat like this might help?
EDIT: it was mentioned here: https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/faq.html#why-does-my-asset-e-g-image-video-model-not-load